Binding data attributes with lit element?
How do we map a property to an attribute when using data-attributes with lit element?
For example suppose we have a property like this:
@property({ type : String }) language = 'xml';

And it's set like this on the component:
<my-element data-language></my-element>

How do we bind the language property to the data-language attribute?

Configure attribute in the @property configuration object.
  /**
   * The language property as a data attribute.
   */
  @property({ type: String, attribute: 'data-language' })
  language: string = 'xml';


